# Charles Darwin's dog in 1858

Tags: 19th-century, victorian

What would have been the breed and name of Charles Darwin's dog at Down House in 1858?
The black and white retriever (Bob) which appears in a photo dated 1863, the Pomeranian (Snow) or someone else?

Comment: The actual photo would be very helpful. Care to post it?

Comment: I don't need to identify the dog from the picture, Bob was a retriever. I need to know the historical information concerning what dog Darwin owned in 1858, either confirming that provided or suggesting another.